# what is the use of overriding ViewWillLayoutSubviews

Tags: ios, autolayout, ios-autolayout, autoresizingmask

I read that its not advisable to do Autolayout or Autoresizing in ViewWillLayoutSubviews then why would they allow it to be overriden.

I thought this is the right place for updating constraints but it turns out thats wrong.

Can somebody help me understand how this event can be used by developers ?

Comment: You need to use viewWillLayoutSubviews() function when you want to perform some task just before any element changes its size or position in the view controller. When you are going to make an application, those 2 functions are rarely used in worst case scenarios.

Comment: That's a very vague question... What exactly are you trying to do? `viewWillLayoutSubviews` may, or may not, be a good place for your task.

Comment: I'm trying to update height constraint of parent view here .. because my logic is whenever there is a change in anyview's constraints this event will get called so here I thought i would change parent view's height according to the element's size it contains

Comment: @TusharSharma - when you want to perfom some task u mentioned what kind of tasks we can do here

Comment: *"I thought i would change parent view's height according to the element's size it contains"* ... well, that is the intent of using auto-layout - so you don't *have* to change the constraints when a size changes. That's why I'm saying your question is vague. Perhaps if you showed exactly what you are trying to do, you would find out that you might be approaching it incorrectly, and you may not even need `viewWillLayoutSubviews` at all.